# Change single ListView item

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm stuck on changing a single row in a populated ListView for several days now and tried lots of (java) solutions found on here as well on [xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data) but as a student I see often solutions posted without proper documentation on how and why it works. So far I have created this custom Adapter for the stock ListView:

```
//How I initialize the Adapter and ListView
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            List<string> online = new List<string>();
            CustomAdapter lvOnlineAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, online);
            ListView lvOnline = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvOnline);
            lvOnline.Adapter = lvOnlineAdapter;

            lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test1");
            lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test2");
            lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test3");

            for(int i = 0; i < lvOnlineAdapter.Count; i++)
                lvOnlineAdapter.EditItem(i, "Test " + i + " Description")

            lvOnlineAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }




    public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter<string> 
{
    List<string> items;
    Activity context;
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<string> items) : base() 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public void Add(string itemToAdd)
    {
        items.Add (itemToAdd);
    }
    public void Remove(string itemToRemove)
    {
        items.Remove (itemToRemove);
    }
    public void Remove(int position)
    {
        items.RemoveAt(position);
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public void EditItem(int Position, string Text2)
    {  //Here is my problem, it does not change anything
        View view = GetView (Position, null, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = Text2;
    }
    public override string this[int position] 
    {  
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count 
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position];
        return view;
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I use EditItem it doesn't change anything, can someone please explain why it doesn't work and what I got to do to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        lvOnlineAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, online);
        lvOnline = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvOnline);
        lvOnline.Adapter = lvOnlineAdapter;

        lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test1");
        lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test2");
        lvOnlineAdapter.Add("Test3");
        lvOnlineAdapter.EditItem(2, "test");
        for( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++ )
            if( myLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof TextView )
            {
                TextView tvBold = (TextView) myLayout.getChildAt( i );
                if(tvBold.getText().ToString() == "test")
                    tvBold.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
            }
    }

public void EditItem(int Position, string Text2)
{
    items[Position] = Text2;
    NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to change it on a ItemClick but when for example the device gets a notification from a user that is in the ListView. So the user will see which user the notification came. 
Problem is right now that I can not change the text once it is added in the ListView or am I missing your point?

Comment: now i understand, you need to put NotifyDataSetChanged(); in your adapters add method

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem, I can't change a single row using the SetNotification(int Position, string Text2). Not adding and removing items because that works.

Comment: create an Edit(String itemToEdit) method and put in it NotifyDataSetChanged() after you change the item

Comment: Well I do but that is what the question is about, EditItem (I renamed the method SetNotification to clear it up) does not change the item displayed. I appreciate your help.

Comment: that's because you are not calling EditItem in your code. You need to call EditItem instead of lvOnlineAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();. Also i think you need to change the item from the list for this to work not the TextView

Comment: Well, I only showed how I initialized it and how my adapter would not completely work, I expanded the example.

Comment: like i said try changing the item at the position not the TextView and add NotitfyDataSetChanged(), your EditItem method should look like in my answer.

Comment: That works fine indeed, thank you :). However I would like to change a property like Bold or BackColor to make a change more obvious, and set the 2nd line of text in the simpleListItem2.

Comment: I think that all of your TextViews will have the same Id, so this is the only workaround that comes into mind. Get all of the TextView from the layout and see which one has the text that you modified. The problem appears if you will have more than 1 field with that text. I've started working with android only a few days ago so tell me if this helps, if not I will keep searching

Comment: Works great on a simpleListItem1, Thank you :D